# How to cast bindingdatasource to datatable?

Tags: c#, casting, datatable, bindingsource

I'm trying to cast the bindingdatasource to datatable using this code

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)gvSideMember.DataSource;
        DataTable tCxC = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;
```

throws error unable to cast bindingsource to datatable

then i tried this code

```
 private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = ((DataTable)dgv.DataSource).Copy();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (!column.Visible)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(column.Name);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

it again show me same error

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(args);
        dt = dv.ToTable();
```

but i don't know what is the base class of DataSourceSelectArguments ? So I can't how can i do this cast?

Comment: what have you set in the datasource of the bindingsource??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `bs.DataSource` is actually another `BindingSource`, so you can try this:

```
var source = bs.DataSource;
while(source is BindingSource){
  source = ((BindingSource)source).DataSource;
}
if(source is DataTable){
  var table = (DataTable) source;
}//else there is not any DataTable we can extract.
```

Comment: where do i put gvSideMember?

Comment: @buddy my code does not involve `gvSideMember`, it involves `bs` and how do you get `bs`? it's clearly that you got it from `gvSideMember`.

Comment: its doing nothing during debug it doesnot enter in not in while and not in other if

Comment: @buddy you have this `(DataTable)bs.DataSource` and it throws this *unable to cast bindingsource to datatable*. So why the hell it throws like so? that means `bs.DataSource` should be a `BindingSource` and hence the `while` loop should be entered and loop at least 1 time.

Comment: realy it is not entering in while loop

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution which also works if you are using BindingSource as n child level.

```
    public static DataTable Table(this DataGridView dgv)
    {
        DataTable dt;
        if (dgv.DataSource is BindingSource)
            dt = ((BindingSource)dgv.DataSource).Table();
        else if (dgv.DataSource is DataSet)
            dt = ((DataSet)dgv.DataSource).Tables[dgv.DataMember];
        else if (dgv.DataSource is DataTable)
            dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
        else
            dt = null;
        return dt;
    }

    public static DataTable Table(this BindingSource bs)
    {
        var bsFirst = bs;
        while (bsFirst.DataSource is BindingSource)
            bsFirst = (BindingSource)bsFirst.DataSource;

        DataTable dt;
        if (bsFirst.DataSource is DataSet)
            dt = ((DataSet)bsFirst.DataSource).Tables[bsFirst.DataMember];
        else if (bsFirst.DataSource is DataTable)
            dt = (DataTable)bsFirst.DataSource;
        else
            return null;

        if (bsFirst != bs)
        {
            if (dt.DataSet == null) return null;
            dt = dt.DataSet.Relations[bs.DataMember].ChildTable;
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.

Comment: The child check causes "null" to be returned on a valid table if you don't have a child. If you don't have a child, just comment out this section and it works fine. Nice.