# VB.net DataGridview Filtering 2013

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, filter

I have created a `Datagridview` that displays all Data. I now want to be able to filter my data. I am using a `DataSet`, `BindingSource` and `TableAdapter`. I tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Currently I have a `TextBox` that should filter when written. When I execute and type in the box it doesnt filter or error out. Below is the code that I have. Am I missing Something?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = True

    Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("")
    adap = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT res_snbr, First_Name, Last_Name, Item FROM Inventory_Details", cn)

    Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adap)
    adap.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
    'adap.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
    'adap.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand()

    dt = New DataTable()
    adap.Fill(dt)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        InventoryDetailsBindingSource.Filter = _
                String.Format("res_snbr Like '%" & TextBox1.Text) & "%'"
    Else
        InventoryDetailsBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=")
Dim adap As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT res_snbr, First_Name, Last_Name, Item FROM Inventory_Details", cn)
Dim builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adap)
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim InventoryDetailsBindingSource As New BindingSource
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    adap.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
    adap.Fill(dt)
    InventoryDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = dt
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InventoryDetailsBindingSource
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.TextLength > 0 Then
        InventoryDetailsBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("res_snbr Like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
    Else
        InventoryDetailsBindingSource.Filter = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you wish to do here, the code above is how I would do it. Among other differences, please note that the `BindingSource` is being used as the the `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`, and the correct use of `String.Format` when setting the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you --------- I reseached this for way to long..... Still came up short. That worked very well!!! I guess I needed this -   InventoryDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = InventoryDetailsBindingSource

Answer (score 0):

If your datasource is a datatable you can try this.

```
TryCast(InventoryDetailsBindingSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text)
```

You can use the row filter property on the datatable as shown here.
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Comment: It gives an error of Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: What is the type of your datasource?

Comment: SQL Server if thats what you are asking

Comment: No, is it a datatable? Provide the code where you populate the datasource.

Comment: Try this if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20424219/how-to-cast-bindingdatasource-to-datatable

Comment: I am coding in VB.net not C#

Comment: 1. Where does the 'InventoryDetailsBindingSource' get populated. Try replacing that with DataGridView1.DataSource and see if my code works.

2. C# and VB.Net code can be converted. Learn to use the internet tools.

Comment: Use TryCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Field = '{0}'", textBoxFilter.Text)

Please mark this as answer if it works.