# How to cast data from BindingSource to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, bindingsource

```
    BindingList<DocumentField> bindingList = new BindingList<DocumentField>(args.recognizedFields);
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
    dataGridDocumentFields.DataSource = source;
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)(((BindingSource)source.DataSource).DataSource);
```

Last line throws following exception;

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to
>   type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20424312/2130976

Comment: `source.DataSource` is a `BindingList<DocumentField>`. You can't cast it to `DataTable`, they are different types.

Comment: I can see values on datagridview, but i cant access. I need get spesific cell values from datagridview or from datatable.

Comment: What is `DocumentField` and `args.recognizedFields`? Can you show the gridview?

Comment: Datagridview includes personal data such as Id,Name, Surname, etc.. For example I want to get Name Where Id = 1

Comment: You can't cast the data source to `DataTable` because it's **not** a `DataTable`, but `BindingList<DocumentField>`. What really are you trying  to achieve with that code?